Magento 2 Configurable child products stock wrong on orderconfirmation
I have M2 2.4.5-p1 and have made a lot of configurable products.
My problem is now that the stock of the child products for the configurable products does not work.
When an order is made the product is shown as backorder on the orderconfirmation even when it has stock on it.
How do I fix this issue so the stock of the child products will be correct.
I have backorder enable on my site.
